# Script to connect Mysql from EC2 to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, rds

I'm writing a script to connect mysql server on an EC2 to RDS, normally I do this:

`mysql -h $RDS_ENDPOINT -P 3306 --user=$RDS_MYSQL_USERNAME --password=$RDS_MYSQL_PASSWORD`

and then `exit`

I just want to establish the connection, nothing else

Now I need to put these commands into a script to automate this process without typing exit. I got 2 issues: the `mysql` is not found when I run bash; and how do I exit mysql from script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

RDS_MYSQL_ENDPOINT="your-endpoint-goes-here";
RDS_MYSQL_USER="your-username-goes-here";
RDS_MYSQL_PASS="your-password-goes-here";
RDS_MYSQL_BASE="your-database-name-goes here";

mysql -h $RDS_MYSQL_ENDPOINT -u $RDS_MYSQL_USER -p$RDS_MYSQL_PASS -D $RDS_MYSQL_BASE -e 'quit';

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "MySQL connection: OK";
else
    echo "MySQL connection: Fail";
fi;
```

Now, the problem you're facing is because you probably don't have the MySQL client installed. To do it on a Ubuntu/Debian system, just type:

`sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client`

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the `-e` tip, I got it working by this command `mysql -h $RDS_ENDPOINT -P 3306 --user=$RDS_MYSQL_USER --password=$RDS_MYSQL_PASS -e 'quit'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a mysql client. Choose what fits your current linux distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

or

```
yum install mysql
```